# How to get mobile reistration ID using GSM Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing android app in titanium,by button click event I have to get registration ID from GCM. how to do that I am new to titanium.

I followed this http://iamyellow.net/post/40100981563/gcm-appcelerator-titanium-module, but I am not able to understand how to implement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement push notification, you should use [Ti.CloudPush](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.CloudPush) module.

You can achieve GCM Push Notification in 6 easy steps

1. Setting up Google Cloud Messaging
2. Push Configuration in ACS Console
3. CloudPush Module Implementation
4. Retrieve Device Token
5. Cloud User Login
6. Subscribe a Channel

**1. Setting Up GCM**

To use GCM, you need to create a Google API project to obtain a Google API key and GCM sender ID. For instructions on creating and obtaining these items, see [Android Developer: Getting Started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and follow the directions in "Creating a Google API Project", "Enabling the GCM Service" and "Obtaining an API Key".

We will use our **Project number** as **GCM Sender ID**.

When creating a new server key, you are asked for a list of IP addresses to accept requests from. Do not enter any information in the textbox and click Create to accept all IP addresses.

**2. Push Configuration in the ACS**

Go to [your apps](https://my.appcelerator.com/apps), then go to My Apps -> Manage ACS -> DEVELOPMENT -> Settings/Android Push Configuration and enter your Google API key in the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) API Key textbox and GCM sender ID in the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Sender ID textbox. (which we got from Step 1)

**3. CloudPush Module Implementation**

- Add CloudPush module into your application.

  To add CloudPush module, you need to add `<module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>` in your TiApp.xml. Then require the module in your javascript file using `var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');`.
- To use push notifications, in the tiapp.xml file, you need to specify push type to GCM.

To do this go to your tiapp.xml.

Add/edit the following lines

```
<property name="acs-push-type-development" type="string">gcm</property>
<property name="acs-push-type-production" type="string">gcm</property>
<property name="acs-push-type" type="string">gcm</property>
```

**4. Retrieve Device Token**

Call the retrieveDeviceToken method before setting the enabled property to true to enable the device to receive push notifications. You must call retrieveDeviceToken before any other CloudPush API call or else the device will not receive push notifications.

```
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var deviceToken = null;
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
    },
    error: function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
    }
});
```

**5. Cloud User Login**

Before subscribe for Push Notification, cloud user should logg in.

```
Cloud.Users.login({
    login: username,
    password: password
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert("login success");
    } else {
        alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

**6. Subscribe a Channel**

You need to subscribe to a channel to get the pushnotification. Push notification will be sending to the particular channel and it will be reached to all users who subscribed to the channel.

```
if(deviceToken != null){
   Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
       channel: 'yourchannelName',
       device_token: deviceToken,
       type: 'gcm' //here i am using gcm, it is recommended one
   }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
           alert('Subscribed for Push Notification!');
       } else {
           alert('Subscribe error:' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
       }
   });
} else {
   alert('You need to retrieve the device token first');
}
```

Now you can send push notification. To do this go to My Apps -> Manage ACS -> DEVELOPMENT -> Push Notifications, here you can see number of clients subscribed for push notification, channels etc. You can send the push notification from there.

**UPDATE : Attention!!**

1. GCM supports devices that run Android 2.2 and later
2. Google Play Store application should be installed in your device.
3. For pre-4.0 devices, the user is required to set up their Google account.
4. You're using an android device for testing, not emulator(Since you can't install Google Play in your emulator).
5. Google play service is running on your device.

The following links will help you:

- [Titanium.CloudPush](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.CloudPush)
- [Android SDK Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/android)
- [ACS Push Notification Using GCM](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2013/10/acs-push-notification-using-gcm.html)

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for your response I tried above one, but what are the uername and passwords.

Comment: I followed all the above steps, I am getting, error: "Failed to register for push! Google Play Services is not ready. Error:SERVICE_INVALID" how to resolve this?

Comment: Check the following 1. You're using an android device for testing, not emulator. 2. Your device should have Google Play Store application installed. 3. You have configured Gmail in your mobile. 4. Your app minimum version is android 2.2 or above since GCM support only from Android 2.2 or above. 5. Google play service is running on your device.

Comment: wow its wondering the way you are explained. thanking you Anand. and what are the username and password?

Comment: You need to create a user account using Cloud.Users module. Also you need to specify the reciever's userid while sending the push notification.

Comment: Hi Anand, when I received a push message I am getting alert with **unfortunately app_name shutdown** , what was the problem. I implemented all the code in app.js

Comment: Can you check the error log, or try to debug the application and please provide me the error message

Comment: Hi Anand,some how I am done, but now getting this error **Invalid email/username**, how to resolve? I am using docs appeceleratoer login email and password(is this correct one or not?). PLease give valid suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you please check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290467/titanium-app-not-working-by-keeping-modal-property-for-window

Comment: Do I need to change/add anything in manifest file?? permisstions to get push notifications. Thanks in advance

Comment: `'type: 'gcm' //here i am using gcm, it is recommended one` The recommended right now is 'android' !

Comment: `You're using an android device for testing, not emulator` Genymotion had a image for Android 4.2.2 with Google Play Services, but recently they have drop it.

Comment: Great post! Could you confirm that Google credential "Registration ID" is actually ACS "Device Token"? ref: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: @FernandoFabreti: 'type: 'gcm' //here i am using gcm, it is recommended one The recommended right now is 'android' ! **Now Appecelerator only supports GCM**. That is why I recommended `gcm` instead of `android` and I believe Google credential "Registration ID" is Device Token in the case of Titanium applications